# Command executes fine in terminal, not in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
if $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug")
then
    kill $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug" -o pid=)
    echo "exists"
fi
```

It returns: "PID: command not found"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest: `if ps -C "bm_d21_debug"`

Comment: You'll want to read the `pkill` man page. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: It's just weird that if I copy and paste 
   kill $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug" -o pid=)
it works fine. but if I copy and paste this whole block, it dies on that line:
   kill $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug" -o pid=

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) automatically detects [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2091). You can have your editor point them out on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this line:

```
if $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug")
```

You execute the `ps` command in a command substitution, which returns the command output. The `if` command then tries to *run that **output** as a **command***.

The first word of the ps output is `PID`, which `if` will handle as the command name. Thus, the "command not found" error.

You just want

```
if ps -C "bm_d21_debug" >/dev/null; then
    echo running
else
    echo NOT running
fi
```

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use square brackets also:

```
if [[ $(ps -C "bm_d21_debug") ]]
```

But this command will always return "yes" ($? = 0)

Comment: Square brackets scare me, but I fixed it by changing to this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846069/11107107 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing to

```
if ps aux | grep ./bm_d21_debug | grep -v grep >/dev/null;then
    pid=$(ps aux | grep ./bm_d21_debug | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
    kill $pid
    echo $pid
fi
```